What function minimizes the distance to its argument?
Let $d$ be a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function.
I am interested in functions that satisfy the following property.

For all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
d(f(x), x) \leq d(f(y),x).
$$

In other words: $f(x)$ minimizes the distance to $x$.
Some functions that trivially satisfy this property, for any $n$ and any metric $d$, are:

The identity function $f(x) = x$;
Any constant function $f(x) = C$.

A less trivial example, for $n=1$ and the standard metric, is the following function, for any constant $C$:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
C  & x<C
\\
x & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$
QUESTIONS:

Is there a term for this property?

Is there a characterization of functions satisfying this property, at least for some common metrics? (I am mainly interested in $\ell_p$ metrics).


NOTE: The property is motivated by game theory. Assume that a person lives in point $x$, and some useful facility should be built in point $f(x)$. The person wants the facility to be as close as possible to $x$. If the function satisfies the property in question, it means that the best strategy for the person is to supply the true $x$; otherwise, it may be better for the person to lie and provide some other location $y$.

If $d$ is induced by a scalar product, then projection to a linear subspace satisfies the condition.

@SassatelliGiulio so $f$ satisfies the property iff there exists a closed set $C$ such that $f(x) = \arg \min _{y\in C} d(x,y)$?

$\newcommand{argmin}{\operatorname{argmin}}$By definition, a function is like yours if and only if $f(x)\in\argmin\limits_{y\in\operatorname{im}f} d(y,x)$. Moreover, $\operatorname{im}f$ is necessarily closed, because $d(f(x),x)=d(x,\operatorname{im}f)$, therefore $x\in\overline{\operatorname{im}f}\Rightarrow f(x)=x$.
Vice versa, given $C\ne\emptyset$ closed, any function $f$ such that $f(x)\in\argmin_{y\in C} d(y,x)$ is like yours (and notice that, with axiom of choice, there is at least one as soon as $C\ne \emptyset$).
It's entirely possible that none of these functions is continuous: namely, this is the case for $C=S^{n-1}$.
Apparently, this is essentially the notion of metric projection. Given a metric space $(X,d)$ and a subset $S$, the metric projection associated to $S$ is the function $P_S:X\to \mathcal P(X)$, $$P_S(x)=\{y\in S\,:\, d(x,y)=d(x,S)\}=\argmin_{y\in S} d(y,x).$$ If $P_S(x)$ is never empty, then $S$ is closed. If $X$ has the Heine-Borel property, then this becomes an if-and-only-if.
The subsets for which $P_S$ is a single-valued function (in your language, $S$ is such that there is exactly one total function with your property and image $S$) are called Chebishev sets. Famous examples of Chebishev sets are non-empty closed convex sets in strictly convex reflexive Banach spaces (see here for references).
